# ng-boostrap modal w/o fullscreen

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I have run into an issue that my modal is always full-screen.

Modal calling btn inside the template:

```
 <button type="button"
        class="btn btn-danger"
        (click)="openRejectModal(rejectTemplate)">Reject</button>
```

ng-template at the end of the html:

```
<ng-template #rejectTemplate>
  <app-reject-modal (close)="closeModal()"
    (send)="sendReject()"></app-reject-modal>
</ng-template>
```

modal component html:

```
<div class="modal-container">

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title"
      id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
    <button type="button"
      class="close"
      aria-label="Close"
      (click)="close.emit()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
        <textarea class="form-control"
          id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"></textarea>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button"
      class="btn btn-outline-dark"
      (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`class="modal-container"` is just a custom css for fiddle currently at: `(width: 60%, height:60%)`

modal opening function:

```
 openRejectModal(template) {
    this.modalService.open(template, { size: 'lg', backdrop: true });
  }
```

options object just added but size and backdrop doesn't change a damn thing... :(

I'd like my modal to be as shown in :
[ng-boostrap documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

But mine is always full-screen.
Whan is the solution to fix this issue?

My modal looks like this atm:
[Pic](https://snag.gy/KWGM0u.jpg)

Comment: Don't wrap everything in a modal-container. Use the markup as shown in the examples of the documentation. The respect of the markup matters, since you're relying on the bootstrap css rules, that expect this markup. And if you want a custom component to be used for the modal, do as the "
Components as content" example shows, and don't use an ng-template

Comment: it's not 100% clear why it is necessary to make a modal.module ts file. Can you elaborate on that for me?

Comment: It's not necessary.

Comment: No full screen? Hmm alright, do you mean you want a small/smaller modal size?

Comment: @wentjun added an edit with a link to my current modal look and that's not what i want.

Comment: Thanks @AlexBene, can I see your component.ts code when you call the .open() method for the modal?

Comment: @wentjun made another edit for you

Comment: Hmm.. Does changing size to 'sm' work? Also, no need for `backdrop: true` because it is true by default

Comment: @wentjun sm makes no difference

Comment: I think I am running out of ideas. I hope you didn't mutate the CSS properties anywhere else?

Comment: @wentjun honestly this is an ongoin project @ our company i hope that nobody messed with the built in css properties. I've just checked styiles.scss contains .modal related entries, so your guess is right i think

Comment: @AlexBene I have a nuclear option. I will post it on as an answer as it is too long as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [NgBoostrap API documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModalOptions), we can pass the `windowClass` property with a custom class which will be appended to the modal.

Here, on the method that calls the opening of the modal, we will pass the class of `custom-modal` to the `windowClass` property:

```
open(content) {
  this.modalService.open(template, {windowClass : 'custom-modal'})
}
```

Add the following on your CSS to overwrite the width. You may replace the 400px with any value which you see fit.

```
.custom-modal .modal-dialog {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

You may need to add the above on your global CSS (or, the `style.css` file that is on the same directory level as your `index.html`) as it may or may not work if you put it within your component's css.

Comment: not 100% solves the problem, but close to it. We have some custom classes that overwrites the default sizes (for mobile view) and that's interfering with my modal.

Comment: Oh no.. That is strange. But that only affects the mobile view right? It does not affect the desktop view or something. I guess you might to edit the mobile view CSS classes/properties..

Comment: I don't know 100% but we can work this out together. Thanks for the help tho ;)